# CSS selector not resolved when using UI Binder

Tags: html, css, gwt, uibinder

Basically, I am building a horizontal navigation bar. I have following markup:

```
<ui:style src="../common.css" type="client.resources.HomeResources.Style">
    @external gwt-Anchor;
    .gwt-Anchor {
        text-decoration: none;
    }
</ui:style>
<g:HTMLPanel styleName="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li><g:Anchor ></g:Anchor> |</li>
        <li><g:Anchor ></g:Anchor> |</li>
        <li><g:Anchor ></g:Anchor> |</li>
        <li><g:Anchor ></g:Anchor> |</li>
        <li><g:Anchor ></g:Anchor> |</li>
        <li><g:Anchor ></g:Anchor> |</li>
        <li><g:Anchor ></g:Anchor></li>
    </ul>
```

`common.css` has following rules:

```
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 25px;
}

ul li {
    display: inline;
    text-align: right;
}

ul li a {
    color: #0077C0;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    padding: 4px 0 4px 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul li a:HOVER {
    color: #F0721C;
}
```

When using rules as defined above, everything works perfect. The problem is that I have `ul` elements in other parts of page, so I've added `div.navbar` before each rule like this:

```
div.navbar ul{}
div.navbar ul li{}
etc...
```

But those rules are not applied to `ul` elements inside UI Binder template. What's wrong with my code?

Here is the generated HTML (normally on one line):

```
<div class="navbar"><ul>
   <li><a class="gwt-Anchor">Item 1</a> |</li>
   <li><a class="gwt-Anchor">Item 2</a> |</li>
   <li><a class="gwt-Anchor">Item 3</a></li>
</ul></div>
```

---

#### RESOLVED

`styleName="navbar"` must be `styleName="{style.navbar}"`

Comment: Not sure about GWT, but what's the HTML that's outputted? There may be other rules with `text-decoration`, whether more general or more specific, that may be causing this as well. Could you find and paste those too?

Comment: @BoltClock, i've edited my question. There are no other rules, i'm looking at firebug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only ask because you didn't include this in your example code: have you double checked there is a `<div class="navbar">` that wraps the `ul`?

Also, if `<g:HTMLPanel styleName="navbar">` is generating the div, it is not closed in the code your provided. Maybe you need a `</g:HTMLPanel`?

Comment: I assume `<g:HTMLPanel styleName="navbar">` generates such an element, but yes, we need to see the generated markup to be sure.

Comment: @bookcasey i've pasted only part of code. I've edited my question to include generated html as seen by firebug.

Comment: Is there an alternative way of specifying selectors for ul and li elements so that there is no conflict with such elements in other parts of the page?